# can I have two views embedded in different UINavigationControllers in succession?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

In xcode 6 I was able to have two views still 'show' segue each other successfully regardless if they were embedded in two different navigationControllers, like so:

[image]
However now, when I implement this setup, the second view it presented modally rather then shown from the previous view, and the shared navigationBar attributes set programmatically are not passed on to the latter view.. is this just an Xcode 7 issue? because I pulled this off successfully in Xcode 6 as I stated.. ANY suggestions ?

Comment: The setup you have shown in the screen shot _is_ a modal segue.

Comment: yes wrong screenshot, just updated @matt

Comment: is there any reason for this odd behavior ? @matt

Comment: There is nothing "odd". I am looking right at the screenshot. There is a nav controller with a root view controller, a modal segue, and a nav controller with a root view controller. You are getting a presented view controller because that's what you've asked for.

Comment: However, you should not in any case be pushing a navigation controller into a navigation controller. Apple does do that but it is deep voodoo and is unsupported behavior for ordinary mortals like you and me. If you were getting away with this before, that was a bug. And now it has been closed, I guess.

Comment: but it still presents the view controller even with a show segue.. and I'm sorry but i highly doubt that explanation. No bug that blatant would hold up for so long, especially in the storyboard.. @matt